# why do you need to add one on new char (str.length())?

Tags: c++, string

Code:

```
string str = "Whats up";
char *c = new char[str.length() + 1];
```

I can still write `char *c = new char[str.length()];`

What is the point of adding +1 on length?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string Isn't that explained in the place you got that code from?

Comment: To make room for the trailing null. You should be using strdup() in any case, and free() to release it.

Answer (score 7):

Your code:

```
string str = "Whats up";
char *c = new char[str.length() + 1];
```

Your question:

> What is the point of adding +1 on length?

The real question should be: What is the point of using C-style strings at all in your C++ program? Are you sure you need them?

Let me explain what exactly happens in your two code lines:

`"Whats up"` is a **string literal**, i.e. a constant series of characters, a `char const[9]` to be precise. The 9th character is the **null character**, `'\0'`, automatically added by the compiler. So the array actually looks like this:

```
{ 'W', 'h', 'a', 't', 's', ' ', 'u', 'p', '\0' }
```

In fact, you could as well write:

```
char const array[9] = { 'W', 'h', 'a', 't', 's', ' ', 'u', 'p', '\0' };
std::string s = array;
```

So you have a `char const[9]` array which is used to initialize a `std::string`. Which constructor of `std::string` is actually used here? If you take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string, you will find this one:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Remember, `std::string` is actually a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`, so your `CharT` in this case is a `char`, and the constructor reads as:

```
string( const char* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Also ignore the `alloc` parameter. It's too complicated to explain to a beginner, and it has a default argument precisely so that you can ignore it almost all the time. Which means that you end up with:

```
string( const char* s);
```

Which is itself another way of writing:

```
string(char const *s);
```

So you can initialize `std::string` with a `char const *`, and your code passes the constructor a `char const[9]`. This works because the **array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element**.

So `std::string` takes your array, treats it as a pointer and copies the 9 characters. The array size information, `9`, is lost, but it doesn't matter, because you have the terminating `'\0'`, so the `std::string` knows where to stop.

So far, so good. You have a `std::string` object which contains a copy of `"Whats up"`. Your next line goes like this:

```
char *c = new char[str.length() + 1];
```

First of all, consider `str.length()`. The `length` function returns ***string* size, not *array* size**. So although you passed 9 characters to construct the string, `length` returns 8. This makes sense, because `std::string` is designed to let you forget about pointers, arrays and memory operations. It's text, and the text here has 8 characters.

Thus, `str.length() + 1` equals *8 + 1 = 9*, so your line of code is equivalent to:

```
char *c = new char[9];
```

You have created a pointer named `c`, initialised to point to a memory location where there is enough ***room* for 9 characters**, although what's currently stored there is **undefined**, so you must not try to read from there yet:

```
c
|
|
+------+
       |
       v
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
...|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ...
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

And there is no relationship between the `std::string` you created and the memory `c` points to. They live in completely different places:

```
 c
 |
 |
 +------+
        |
        v                                   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... |W |h |a |t |s |  |u |p |\0| ...
 +-+-+-+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8           ^
                                            |
                                            |
           str -------( c_str() )-----------+
```

But if you use a C function like `strcpy` to copy the contents of the `std::string` to those 9 characters, then it becomes clear why you need space for 9 characters:

```
strcpy(c, str.c_str());
```

`strcpy` looks at the source (`str.c_str()`) and copies one character after the other to `c` until it finds `'\0'`. `str` internally ends with `\0`, so all is good. The function goes from *0* to *8* on the right of this picture and copies everything to *0* to *8* on the left.

And this finally answers your question: There must be space for 9 characters on the left. Otherwise, `strcpy` will attempt to write the final character (`\0`) to a memory location you are not allowed to touch. Which results in undefined behaviour and may cause e.g. crashes or random crashes.

With room for 9 characters, `strcpy` finished successfully:

```
 c
 |
 |
 +------+
        |
        v                                   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
... |  |W |h |a |t |s |  |u |p |\0|  | ... |W |h |a |t |s |  |u |p |\0| ...
 +-+-+-+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8           ^
                                            |
                                            |
           str -------( c_str() )-----------+
```

---

Moral of the story:

Use `std::string`. Copying a `std::string` may use very similar mechanism inside but frees you (among other annoying things) from having to remember the "+ 1" rule:

```
std::string s1 = "Whats up";
std::string s2 = "...";
s2 = s1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `std::string`, C-style strings use a special character to indicate its end, which is the null character `'\0'`, the extra one character is used to store the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: your answer could be misleading.  'std::string' also uses a '\0'. the 'c_str()' method returns a pointer to the underlying data, which is null-terminated

Answer (score -6):

There is a flaw in your code.

It should be

```
c* = new char[str.length()+1];
```

s.length()+1 wouldn't do anything.

Although the compiler will automatically set the c string size for you, it's good practice to specify the exact size so you get to see the mechanics of everything.

C strings always need one more space than the std::string value because c strings are character arrays that have a terminating null value at the end of the array.  That is why you always give room for the NULL at the end.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: But "Although the compiler will automatically set the c string size for you..." sounds quite wrong.

Comment: why dont you go and try it before you downvote and call me wrong?

go ahead go make a - new char[anyValue]

and make that char = "anyNumberOflettersYouWish"
and watch the compiler go to work.

Comment: Try what exactly? A memory leak? Oh, a compiler error (invalid conversion from `const char*` to `char`)

Comment: Here, let me try clarifying for you since you seem to be having trouble with brief explanations.

    'code'char* text;

Comment: Why don't you post some real code in your answer to explain how you could use the compile time length of a string literal in a situation where you are trying to `new` a `char` array and fill it with the contents of an `std::string`?

Comment: Here, let me try clarifying for you since you seem to be having trouble with brief explanations.

`char* text = new char[1];` `text = "abcdefg";` `std::cout<<text;`

believe it or not, that code will actually compile and display, even though you set the text to `char[1]`

Comment: @savageWays: The conversion from non-const `char*` to const `char*` is deprecated and yields a compiler diagnostic. And initializing `text` with the result of `new` and then assigning it something else can create a memory leak if this piece of code is executed repeatedly in your program.

Comment: *"Although the compiler will automatically set the c string size for you, it's good practice to specify the exact size so you get to see the mechanics of everything."* - This sentence is dangerously misleading, or plain wrong. What you perhaps meant to say is that the compiler automatically adds `'\0'` to a string literal, i.e. `"abc"` is actually a 4-character array.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yeah, that's how I should've wrote it.  'string literal' was the word I'm looking for.  I'm apparently not a C++ pro just yet.  Also, I'm a pretty new CS student toying around with strings and cstrings.  Just having some fun :) .. thanks for the clarifications..I had no idea I was literally assigning the `char*` to an entirely different value without proper `delete` .. I mistakenly thought I was setting the value of the `new char[1]` to the string literal, and the compiler was automatically resizing the array for me.. OOPS..

Comment: @savageWays: I long for the days of my youth when C strings were fun for me as well. Today they cause me nothing but trouble, headaches, time wasted I could have used for more interesting tasks and debugging sessions deep in legacy code written by people I have never known... :)